# Supplements to Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

I plan to take Analysis I next semester, covering roughly the first 5 chapters of Rudin. I've heard that relying on Rudin alone can be exasperating; are there any recommendations for supplementary material? I supplemented Friedberg with Axler during Linear Algebra and found the combination to be very helpful. Any recommendations for similar combinations in Analysis? Perhaps Apostol?

Comment: Yes, Apostol is fine. I would also highly suggest the book "counterexamples in analysis".

Comment: Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis is also excellent.

Comment: Why not try getting a head start to Rudin now and see if you find it over bearing? I personally found Rudin fine on it's own, especially the first $7$ chapters, and didn't realize that it was common to read it alongside a supplement until after I finished it.

Comment: I don't see why Rudin needs to be accompanied, that one book alone will take you a lot of time anyway. The best supplement is probably just your instructor's office hour.